# space at the beginning of my view's border

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, layer

am adding a border to my view like this:

```
func addBottomBorderWithColor(color: UIColor, width: CGFloat) {
    let border = CALayer()
    border.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height, width: self.frame.size.width, height: width)
    self.layer.addSublayer(border)
}
```

but strangley this works fine on Iphone 7 but in iphone 7 plus .. i will get this result:

[image: screenshot]

as you can see there's a space at the beginning of the view's border.. why?

same thing is happening with view's shadow .. am doing it like this:

```
     func dropShadow(scale: Bool = true) {
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
    layer.shadowRadius = 1
    layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds).cgPath
    layer.shouldRasterize = true
    layer.rasterizationScale = scale ? UIScreen.main.scale : 1
}
```

and getting space at the end of the view on iphone 7 plus

[image]

how to solve it?

Comment: which one right side or else

Comment: and where you called this `addBottomBorderWithColor` in page load or else

Comment: @Anbu.karthik right side .. in the viewdidload()

Comment: in view did load it will not work put it in viewdidAppear method and check it's working or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it means your UI Is not updated , call in **viewdidAppear** or force to update the UI in mainthread on viewdidload using

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   //call your addBottomBorderWithColor
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the `addBottomBorderWithColor` in:

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()


}
```

The UI gets updated according to the constraints after `ViewDidLoad`.